# Trying to update one table from another

Tags: mysql

I've created this query and I can't seem to get it to work. I'll have to admit I'm new at this, I've written some simple queries in the past, but I've never tried to update one table from another before.I've looked at some related posts here, but maybe I'm just being dense... they don't see to help. Here's what I'm using:

```
Insert into `customers_marketing_options` (`created_on`) 
    select `created_on`,
    from `customers`
    where `customers`.`customer_id`= `customers_marketing_options`.`customer_id`;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the help. SO it's the JOIN that I was missing... never used it before. I'll study up on that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE customers_marketing_options 
JOIN customers ON customers.customer_id = customers_marketing_options.customer_id
SET customers_marketing_options.created_on = customers.created_on
```